# Understanding interaction between Swift files - how do I call from one to the other

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I have my ViewController.swift which is the first to run when the app loads. I then segue to another SecondViewController.swift file.

The ViewController.swift instance is still in existence, correct?

So now, from SecondViewController.swift, I call ViewController().someFunction()

The ViewController's "viewDidLoad" does not get called, only the function I specifically called to.

Now: if I instantiate an Int variable in ViewController.swift "var testNum = 2" and in the ViewController's viewDidLoad I change its value to 14. Then I segue to SecondViewController. Then I call to ViewController().someFunction() and I print the value of testNum in that function, I get the instantiated value of 2 instead of the value that ViewController had which was 14, which leads me to believe that I've created a new copy of ViewController by calling a function in this way.

Is that right? Is that what I've done? And if so, is there a way to call a function in the existing ViewController instead of creating a new ViewController from within SecondViewController.swift?

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have my ViewController.swift which is the first to run when the app loads. I then segue to another SecondViewController.swift file.

Nitpicking: You don't segue between 'files', you segue between instances of classes defined in those files.

> The ViewController.swift instance is still in existence, correct?

Yes. Well, the original instance of the class defined in that file, see above.

> So now, from SecondViewController.swift, I call ViewController().someFunction()
>
> The ViewController's "viewDidLoad" does not get called, only the function I specifically called to.

With `ViewController()` you create a new instance of the `ViewController` class and then directly invoke that method on it. Which doesn't make a lot of sense.

> Now: if I instantiate an Int variable in ViewController.swift "var testNum = 2" and in the ViewController's viewDidLoad I change its value to 14. Then I segue to SecondViewController. Then I call to ViewController().someFunction() and I print the value of testNum in that function, I get the instantiated value of 2

When you call `ViewController()` you create a *new* instance of the class defined in the ViewController.swift. Quite (very much) likely this is not what you want to do.
It appears you rather want to hang on to the original instance of that VC. So you need to transfer that when doing the segue.

I'm sure you've read the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html), right? ;-) This is a relevant section:

> The prepareForSegue:sender: method of the source view controller lets you pass data from the source view controller to the destination view controller. The UIStoryboardSegue object passed to the method contains a reference to the destination view controller along with other segue-related information.

Usually you wouldn't want to preserve a reference to the original view controller, but rather transfer relevant data from that into the VC you segue to (to decouple them).

Comment: I'm going with this as the right answer for the explanation that ViewController() does indeed create a new instance of the class. I was attempting to keep all SKProduct/SKPayment/In-App Purchase code in my main ViewController and since the in-app purchase is made from a different view controller, I wanted to call for the purchase with "SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)" in the main ViewController. Instead, I just moved all SKProduct/SKPayment/In-App Purchase code to the view controller from which purchases are made. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be storing values, I'd recommend creating a model class.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

This will keep the data independent of the controllers because, to answer your "The ViewController.swift instance is still in existence, correct?" question, it may or may not be in existence depending on memory. That's why creating a model is desirable because then you're not worried about it.

If you'd like examples, there are many online if you google MVC iOS. Hope that helps.